# Boot looping IBM BladeCenter H AMM

Tags: ibm, bladecenter

We're running IBM BladeCenter H (8852) systems for some years and recently we started to experience a problem. Our AMMs started to die with a very distinct pattern. When we plug an AMM in, its orange (!) LED comes on briefly and when ethernet interface lights its both LED for initialization whole AMM abruptly resets. Sometimes the orange LED lights up again, but the two seems independent from each other. In the end, the AMM can never boot up and we shelve the unit as defective.

We are in the process of transferring the systems, and wonder whether this is a known fault mode and can be remedied. We would like to transfer as many spare parts as possible.

Also, since AMMs never complete boot, we cannot make them stand-by AMMs on running systems and get a new firmware flashed automatically.